# Change Visual Studio ASP.NET HTTPS Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ssl, https

When we turn on SSL in visual studio for an ASP.NET project. Visual studio sends a generated certificate to the browser when we access the debugging localhost site.

I need to change the certificate that visual studio sends to the browser. I have a self signed .PFX certificate file for this.

How can i get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, with local, you mean the "ISS Express" SSL certificate, I suggest you to check this extremely detailed Hanselman [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx).

You should check specifically section 2: *MAKING AN SSL CERT, HOOKING IT UP TO IIS EXPRESS AND MAKING IT TRUSTED*

I guess is what you're looking for. Hope it helps!